# Как разработчики ВКонтакте применили округление (закругление) на видео?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webrtc

Разрабатываю видео звонки на основе webRTC и при получении изображения на SurfaceViewRenderer не могу его закруглить. Похоже что они обернули его в другую, но я не сильно понимаю в какую.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRv9i.png) Помогите разобраться.
На изображении [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIM8n.png) явно видно что в верхней части оно закруглено с помощью CardView, а в нижней части оно не работает, так как нижняя часть лежит поверх другого SurfaceViewRenderer.
[image: подробная картинка того что происходит]
[image: Пример из приложения ВКонтакте. Происходит видео звонок.]

Comment: Предполагаю что он имеет ввиду обычное скругление углов View, два простых варианта использовать shape или CardView. Второй вариант будет попроще, основой для своего видеоView, выставьте к не параметр: cardCornerRadius="4dp"

Comment: @Valeriy, да я пробовал использовать CardView и это эффективный способ, только если у видеоView нет на фоне такого же видеоView. Если так то CardView не помогает. Способ с shape сейчас попробую.

Comment: "только если у видеоView нет на фоне такого же видеоView" - не совсем понял смысл фразы, да и оно не важно, раз нельзя избавится от дублирования. Хотя я вам советую пройтись по этому вопросу.

Comment: @Valeriy, я добавил картинку, чтобы внести ясность в вопрос. Прошу заметить, что в верхней части миниатюра закруглена, а в нижней нет. Это происходит потому что SurfaceViewRenderer лежит на таком же SurfaceViewRenderer, а как это исправить не понятно. Об этом и вопрос.
P.S. Закругление происходит с помощью CardView.

Comment: @Kromster, я добавил картинку чтобы было понятно.

Comment: @Kromster, нет именно закругление (или округление) маленькой SurfaceViewRenderer. Я изменил картинку чтобы было более понятно.

Comment: Теперь ясно. Комментарии удаляю )

Comment: Может быть будет звучать глупо, но попробуйте положить его (CardView) в другое поле, например frameLayout или LinearLayout и придайте ему прозрачный фон. Имеем: surface, layout, cardView, surface. Layout должен быть немного больше CardView (хотя можно перекрыть всё поле и на этом строить свою логику) и задаём ему фон: #00000000. По логике должно работать.

Comment: @Valeriy, пробовал, не помогает. Спасибо)

Comment: Прилепи её тогда к низу экрана, типа так это и задумывалось)

Comment: @Valeriy, нет не выйдет) Так очень плохо смотрится)

Answer (score 0):

### Если можно использовать MaterialComponents

1. Для начала определим в стилях наш шейп:

```xml
<style name="UpperRoundedMCVShape">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">16dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
</style>
```

2. Далее - создадим стиль с наследованием от `Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView`

```xml
<style name="Widget.UpperRoundedMaterialCardView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/UpperRoundedMCVShape</item>
</style>
```

3. Применим стиль в теме приложения (или же, его можно использовать напрямую в layout, через указание style)

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="materialCardViewStyle">@style/Widget.UpperRoundedMaterialCardView</item>
</style>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Если использование MaterialComponents невозможно

Без переопределения CardView простым способом это сделать не получится, но есть костыль:

1. Создаётся Полностью прозрачный CardView
2. В него вкладывается другой, нужный нам CardView
   2.1. В нём устанавливается нужный радиус углов, а также layout_marginTop, равный `радиус-1`

Далее, все нужные нам элементы нужно пихать во вложенный CardView

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="64dp">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_outer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="3dp" >

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view_inner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#12418F"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp" >
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Получается вот такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: P.S. С `support`'овскими CardView это тоже работает